# Extracting column labels of the cells meeting a given condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose the data at hand is in the following form:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,10,20], 'B':[4,40,50], 'C':[10,11,12]})
```

I can compute the minimum by row with:

```
df.min(axis=1)
```

which returns `1 10 12`.

Instead of the values, I would like to create a pandas Series containing the column labels of the corresponding cells.

That is, I would like to get `A A C`.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [idxmin(axis=1)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) method:

```
In [8]: df.min(axis=1)
Out[8]:
0     1
1    10
2    12
dtype: int64

In [9]: df.idxmin(axis=1)
Out[9]:
0    A
1    A
2    C
dtype: object

In [11]: df.idxmin(axis=1).values
Out[11]: array(['A', 'A', 'C'], dtype=object)
```